# Reference the invoking object in the passed block in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda, block, proc

Is there any way to get hold of the invoked object inside the block thats being called. For instance, is there any way for the blocks to get access to the scope of the method `batman` or the class `SuperHeros`

```
class SuperHeros

  attr_accessor :news

  def initialize
    @news = []
  end

  def batman task
    puts "Batman: #{task} - done"
    yield "feed cat"
    @news << task
  end

end

cat_woman = lambda do |task| 
  puts "Cat Woman: #{task} - done" 
  # invoker.news << task
end

robin = lambda do |task| 
  puts "Robin: #{task} - done"
  # invoker.news << task
end


characters = SuperHeros.new
characters.batman("kick Joker's ass", &cat_woman)
characters.batman("break Bane's bones", &robin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something similar to [Instance eval with delegation](http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/ruby-dsls-instance-eval-with-delegation) pattern, used - for example - in [Savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) gem:

```
def batman(task, &block)
  @original_self = eval('self', block.binding)
  puts "Batman: #{task} - done"
  instance_exec('feed cat', &block)
  @news << task
end

private

def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if @original_self
    @original_self.send(method, *args, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

In this approach, when you call method (with implicit receiver) inside block passed into `batman` method, it's called in the context of `SuperHeros` instance. If there is no such method available, the call goes (through `method_missing`) to original block `self`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but can you give a pointer on how to pass parameters to a block while used in instance_eval()

Comment: @JikkuJose you can use `instance_exec` - look at my edited post.

Comment: Oh cool, that works! I didn't use that `method_missing` implementation! And frankly, didn't get what that `original_self` too was for. (This was my modification to the code with your suggestion: http://pastebin.com/ZdHsZ4Ck)

Comment: @JikkuJose I used this in case the method you call in block (with implicit receiver) is not found in `SuperHeros` instance method - then it is delegated to `self` evaluated from block. But, as you already noticed, it's not always necessary. Your solution seems to be enough. 
Please accept my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the receiver object inside a block is assigning the object to an instance variable.

This example illustrate more clearly how the lambdas cat_woman and robin can access to attributes of the receiver objects of blocks:

```
class SuperHeros
  attr_accessor :news, :name, :current_task

  def initialize(a_name)
    @name = a_name
    @news = []
  end

  def batman(task)
    puts "Inside the method batman of #{name}: #{task} in progress ..."
    @current_task = task
    yield
    @news << task
  end

end

cat_woman = lambda do |extra_task|
  puts "cat_woman even #{extra_task} before doing #{@caller_obj.current_task}"
  puts "Cat Woman: #{@caller_obj.current_task} - done by #{@caller_obj.name}"
  # invoker.news << task
end

robin = lambda do |extra_task|
  puts "robin even #{extra_task} before doing #{@caller_obj.current_task}"
  puts "Robin: #{@caller_obj.current_task} - done by #{@caller_obj.name}"
end


character_1 = SuperHeros.new('batman_1')
(@caller_obj = character_1).batman("kick Joker's ass") { cat_woman['eats some burger'] }

puts

character_2 = SuperHeros.new('batman_2')
(@caller_obj = character_2).batman("break Bane's bones") { robin['drinks some beer'] }
```

The output will be:

```
Inside the method batman of batman_1: kick Joker's ass in progress ...
cat_woman even eats some burger before doing kick Joker's ass
Cat Woman: kick Joker's ass - done by batman_1

Inside the method batman of batman_2: break Bane's bones in progress ...
robin even drinks some beer before doing break Bane's bones
Robin: break Bane's bones - done by batman_2
```