# Is it possible for an undeclared enumerable object to be able to call itself within a block?

Tags: ruby, block, self

I recently asked a question today ([Equality test on three or more objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295181/equality-test-on-three-or-more-objects/35295350#35295350)) where I was trying to determine an elegant way to run an equality test on a set of 3 or more objects. One of the solutions turned out to be something like this:

```
array = [1,1,1,1]
array.all? {|x| x == array.first }
```

I'm wondering if it would be possible to reduce this to just one line, so that I could do something *that would be interpreted like this*:

```
[1,1,1,1].all? {|x| x == [1,1,1,1].first }
#=> true
```

where somehow I'm able to reference the initial object being called on by the block without first having to declare that object in a previous line. In pseudo-code what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
[1,1,1,1].all? {|x| x == object_being_called_on_by_block.first }
#=> true
```

I've also tried this, but did not work:

```
[1,1,1,1].all? { |x| x == self.first }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been frequently asked on SO, and is frequently requested as a feature on Ruby core. So far, a Ruby core developer recommends this:

```
[1,1,1,1].tap{|a| break a.all?{|x| x == a.first}}
```

If you don't mind about performance, you can do:

```
[1,1,1,1].instance_eval{all?{|x| x == first}}
```

Comment: I've seen it once here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834086/reference-the-invoking-object-in-the-passed-block-in-ruby, but couldn't get much out of the example. This solution also appears different and simpler. Thanks

Comment: ahh. so in your second example, you could in fact use the `self` keyword but it would be redundant. gotcha.